# Java 8 -> Collectors.toMap -> Duplicate key

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I m trying to convert `List` of available `Currency` to a `Map`, To look up based on Currency Numeric code i want to get String code. Here is the code.

But this code above throwing below error, I m very new to Java 8 hence banging my head :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key YUM
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
    at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1254)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1556)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

But this code above throwing below error, I m very new to Java 8 hence banging my head

```
public class IsoCurrencyCode {

  private static final Set<Currency> ISO_CURRENCY = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();

  private static final Map<Integer, Currency> NUMERIC_MAP = ISO_CURRENCY.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Currency::getNumericCode, Function.identity()));

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    Currency currency = NUMERIC_MAP.get(971);
    System.out.println(currency.getCurrencyCode());
  }
}
```

It should load all currencies into the map with code as keys.

Answer (score 7):

`Collectors.toMap()` doesn't accept duplicates for keys.
Since you have that for `Currency::getNumericCode`, `toMap()` throws this exception when a duplicate key is encountered.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key YUM
```

Note that here the error message is misleading.  Keys are `Integer` while `YUM` is not. `YUM` looks like a `Currency` instance and that is.
Indeed, `YUM` refers to one of the values (`Currency`) processed by `toMap()` that have a duplicate key, not the key value itself.  It is a [Java bug fixed in Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892l).

To solve your issue, either use `Collectors.groupingBy()` to collect to a `Map<Integer, List<Currency>>` and in this case you could have multiple values by key or as alternative merge the duplicate keys with the `toMap()` overload, for example to keep the last entry :

```
private static final Map<Integer, Currency> NUMERIC_MAP = 
ISO_CURRENCY.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Currency::getNumericCode, Function.identity(), (v1, v2)-> v2);
```

---

To answer to your comment, you could find the culprit code (duplicates) in this way :

```
Map<Integer, List<Currency>> dupMap = 
ISO_CURRENCY.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Currency::getNumericCode)
            .entrySet()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(dupMap);
```

Comment: Yeah this works fine. When i debug the currency YUM, there is no duplicate.

Comment: I updated with a sample code that should show you the duplicate(s).